# Synchronous command to restart pc

Tags: command-line, reboot, windows-embedded-7

In my Windows Embedded 7 Standard installation, I'm setting an environment variable using the synchronous command

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Name /t REG_SZ /d "Data"
```

As I have read, I can't access this variable until the next restart of my system. I tried to restart using the following command (I found it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/quebecservicingdeployment/thread/45d0098a-701b-4f18-964f-5bee3e78ee84))

```
cmd /c shutdown /r /f /t 75
```

This did not work for me. (Also calling the command via the regular Cmd.exe-Window is working.)

Is there any way to restart a Windows Embedded 7 Standard OS using synchronous commands? (Or maybe there are other solutions to the problem of accessing the environment variable?)

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle, it eventually worked by copying the line `SHUTDOWN /r /f /t 30` to a batch file and executing the file via a synchronous command. I don't know, why it would not work by just running the line directly...

Answer (score 0):

As I remember the command in `cmd.exe` was like this:
`shutdown -s -r -t 30`
It will restart your computer after 30 Seconds and you should run it with administrator privileges.